# how to create phonegap app using magento soap or rest api

Tags: android, cordova, rest, magento, soap

I want to create an android app using phone gap using Magento soap /rest API. the basic problem I am facing is  when I use rest API, I am  not able to authenticate the  soap user I have created in Magento admin  and  when  I  use soap  I am  able to authenticate but not able to  log in the customer . and  not able to  fetch product images. someone Please advise me which  API I should use  to create app  how should I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to  create custom module and  write own web Services instead of using soap and rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to whitelist your site domain in the Phonegap app.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Since I asked a question you mean?