# Has anyone developed Mobile apps against Magento's backend using Magento's SOAP APIs?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We are trying to make the decision if it is worth proceeding to use the Magento's SOAP APIs for our mobile App or if we should rewrite them as custom REST APIs.

We are using Magento 1.9.2.1 where the support REST APIs is limited, unlike SOAP APIs. To save us time, we would rather use the SOAP APIs but not sure if SOAP is a good for a mobile app in terms of latency compared to REST.

Answer (score 0):

You should   create custom module and create  your own Rest API there. because none of the Magento's soap and rest API are complete .

[how to create phonegap app using magento soap or rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210755/how-to-create-phonegap-app-using-magento-soap-or-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Magento APIs are very slow and not supports all activities hence not recommended.

Create your own custom APIs.

Or use some free or commercial Magento Admin solutions and build over them.